# Save extending class' methods' names in constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have three classes, two of them extending the third. Is it possible to somehow (different than manually) assign extending classes' names to the super constructor?

```
class Master {

    constructor(options) {
        this.methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Master.prototype );
    }

    getMethods() {
        return Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Master.prototype );
    }

}

class SlaveOne extends Master {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }
    methodOne() {}
    methodTwo() {}
}

class SlaveTwo extends Master {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }
    methodThree() {}
    methodFour() {}
}
```

So, what I want is to have either method or `this.methods` assignment in the Master class, which will:

- return `['constructor', 'methodOne', 'methodTwo']` when called on an instance of `SlaveOne`;
- return `['constructor', 'methodThree', 'methodFour']` when called on an instance of `SlaveTwo`;

My current code will return same `['constructor', 'getMethods']` when called either on instance of `SlaveOne`, `SlaveTwo` or `Master`. Any ideas?

Comment: Just get all the methods of `this` object, and the prototypes it inherits from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```js
class Master {

    getMethods() {
        return Object.getOwnPropertyNames( this.constructor.prototype );
    }

}

class SlaveOne extends Master {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }
    methodOne() {}
    methodTwo() {}
}

class SlaveTwo extends Master {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }
    methodThree() {}
    methodFour() {}
}

console.log(new SlaveOne().getMethods(), new SlaveTwo().getMethods())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed.

Comment: Better use `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` instead of `this.constructor.prototype`

Comment: @Bergi Just wonder why it is better in the given case. What might go wrong with `this.constructor.prototype` here?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko The usual thing, `this.constructor` not being the one you thought it would be. Admittedly it's rather unlikely when one uses `class` syntax for inheritance.